# How to identify whether the current data network is Edge or 3G on iPhone

Tags: iphone, networking, core-telephony

Is there a way to figure out the current data network available on iPhone? Whether it is EDGE or 3G?

It works for me even if its doable using core telephony private framework. I am not bothered about app store submission.

I know its very simple to identify whether the user is on Wifi or CellData network. But not able to find a way to identify the network type among edge or 3g?

Pleas also comment if you know a good core telephony documentation/tutorial to refer to.

Comment: yes of course. sorry for not putting it up already.

Comment: This is a duplicate of the following question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1381056/how-to-determine-whether-user-is-on-edge-or-3g-on-iphone

Answer (score 0):

I've never investigated this, you could try to start from the Rechability
example from Apple
http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/Reachability/

Comment: Reachability only tells if the user is on wifi or data network. Thats the farthest it goes.