# Xcode: Check network connection

Tags: ios, xcode, networking, uiimageview, connection

How would I display a certain image depending on whether the iOS device is on the Edge or E networks? This is basically an image which would notify the user that they have bad internet connection.

Thanks,

James

Comment: Have you looked at the [Reachability](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html) sample code from Apple?

Comment: Yes but this doesn't explain how to check if they are on Edge or E I don't think... Didn't see anything...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to determine whether user is on Edge or 3G on iPhone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1381056/how-to-determine-whether-user-is-on-edge-or-3g-on-iphone)

Comment: yes, but http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1381056/how-to-determine-whether-user-is-on-edge-or-3g-on-iphone doesn't answer it entirely...

Comment: It does answer it entirely: the answer is you can't reliably. You can test speed, but not technology.

Comment: but how can I actually find out if they are on Edge or E. That article explained how to check for connection at all or detecting the device itself...

Comment: @pixelbitlabs First of, Edge and E == the same (Hence E). Second, that article is excatly about what you are wondering. Quote: _Though it is relatively straightforward to determine if an iPhone is on Wifi or a data network programmatically in your application, I can't figure out a way to determine if the iPhone is on Edge or 3G._, am I mistaken or is that the exact same question you asked?