# How do I check "Use Mobile Data" setting in iOS?

Tags: ios, mobile

I can't find an answer to this anywhere...  not even in the Apple docs.

In iOS there is a Mobile Data (On/Off) option under Settings>General>Mobile Data.

Is it possible for an app to check whether this option has been set on or off?

Or is it simply reflected in the results of network and reachability calls?  (Reporting no network?)

Comment: Cellular Data/Mobile Data is the 'EDGE' connection.  For an app, it's just check if has connection or not, there's no API to exactly tell you "It's Edge" or "It's 3G". Anyways, seems duplicated of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1381056/how-to-determine-whether-user-is-on-edge-or-3g-on-iphone

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check for an active Internet Connection on iPhone SDK?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083701/how-to-check-for-an-active-internet-connection-on-iphone-sdk)

Answer (score 3):

You can check if user is connected to wifi, Mobile network or 3G network via [Reachability](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html) but you can not open the **settings** via your app.

Comment: Perfect, that's just what I needed to know.  Thanks, nsgulliver!